# Strange Behavior of Image.RotateFlip

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I have a strange behavior of the method `Image.RotateFlip`

I need to manipulate bitmaps with 1 bit depth and when I rotate by 180° an image 512 pixels large, that method shift the image left by some pixels and add a black line on right to fill the leftover space.

```
var image = new Bitmap(@".\spacex_512.bmp");
image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
image.Save(@".\rotate_180.bmp");
```

original:

[image: original]

flipped:

[image: flipped]

It doesn't occur when the image is 511px or 513px wide.

Is it a bug? What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Yep, that looks like a bug. There is an undue shift by 8 pixels (which is the size of a byte). Maybe you can embed the image in one 513 pixels wide, flip and crop.